# Windows 2008 R2: How to unmount/eject a USB device from the command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-server-2008-r2

The subject says it all.

Answer (score 3):

[Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=311272) will allow you to do this. [Here](http://ask-leo.com/is_there_a_way_to_safely_remove_hardware_from_a_batch_file.html) is a good article on how to use it.

Comment: I was trying to find some evidence that it worked with 2008 R2 since that build is for Windows 2003 x86 or IA64 (no x64).  Looks like the current WDK has an updated version. 
See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservercore/thread/c8d7d920-5224-45a9-ad79-ea3a998ec89d

I'll post with confirmation that it works.

Comment: Confirmed: devcon.exe from the latest WDK works on Windows Server 2008 R2 (version 6.1.7600.16385)

Comment: DEVCON asks for admin rights. it's completely useless for guest clients.

Answer (score 0):

This tool even unmounts S-ATA devices (with spin-down):

http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm

Works up to Windows 10 / Server 2016